# Saving array to variable name and retriving in Octave

Tags: save, load, octave

I am trying to store an array in a variable inside a for loop to a file everytime it loops. Also i want to use those files later in another for loop. I have tried to use save and load. However, it is not working. Here is what i have tried:

```
for i=1:5
c=a(a(:,2)==i,:)
filename=sprintf('File_%d.mat',i);
save('-mat',filename,'i');
clear c;
endfor
```

Files for each loop is created but cannot read those files. 
Then I tried to load those files one by one in another for loop as below

```
for i=1:5
filename=sprintf('File_%d.mat',i);
load ('-mat',filename, 'i');
end for
```

I cannot load the files back in the loop. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What doesn't work? You just write "..but cannot read those files" and "I cannot load". So please create a complete example and/or describe whats your problem.

Here my guess what could be your problem:

In the first loop you write i with the value 1 in the file File_1.mat, then i with value 2 in File_2.mat and so on but I think what you really want to write to the file is something calculated from i, for example

```
for i=1:5
 c=a(a(:,2)==i,:)
 filename=sprintf('File_%d.mat',i);
 save('-mat',filename,'c');
 clear c;
endfor
```

and then

```
for i=1:5
 filename=sprintf('File_%d.mat',i);
 load ('-mat',filename, 'c');
 c
endfor
```

btw, your approach looks very dirty. You can store multible vars, cells and arrays to one file...

Comment: Thanks Andy for your suggestions. I had saved i instead of c, which caused the error. Like you said,we can store multiple variables to a file. But, my purpose here is to create multiple files.

Comment: @ushik: Any reason you didn't accept that as answer?

Comment: I have thanked u for ur suggestion. Doesn't it mean I am using ur suggestion. I am new user here So please tell me what else do I need to  do.

Comment: @ushik: I gave you the hint that you are saving "i" and that it's probable that this isn't what you want